# Buffering result from Flowable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have this code that captures images from a *webcam*, 1 image per second.

```
Flowable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(aLong -> {
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = webcam.getImage();
                return bufferedImage;
            }).subscribe(bufferedImage -> {
        if(bufferedImage != null) {
        }
        // Capture 1000 images
    }, error -> {
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    });
```

With RxJava how can I make it buffer 300 images first then that 300 images (probably a Java array) would be passed into a method for processing, say `processImages(bufferedImageArray);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `buffer(count)` operator :

```java
Flowable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(...)
            .buffer(300)
            .subscribe(...)
```